# Can or does oscillation occur from a static electric discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator

If an object with a net static charge, like the metal sphere of a charged Van de Graaff generator is discharged with a wire with a significant inductance, can oscillation occur?  It can if a capacitor, with no net charge, discharges through a component with enough inductance and low enough resistance, but does this occur with this type of discharge?

Comment: What do you mean by "wire with a significance"? I'm guessing "significant inductance" munged by some auto-spell-check. But, yes, there is capacitance between the sphere and ground so it is the same as your circuit example.

Comment: Whoops, yeah that's what I meant to write.